# variable.addEventListener(); not working in Google Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I see lots of examples of code like this

```
variable.addEventListener()
```

or even

```
document.body.addEventListener()
```

in various Javascript tutorial examples and StackOverflow solutions, yet in my Google Chrome extension, these don't work (error message below).

This is the code I'm working with:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton1");
button1.addEventListener("click", handleClick1);
```

I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at [line6]" in the console. I've tried lots of variations of this but I just can't seem to get my "addEventListener" to focus on a specific thing, rather than my whole "document." So far, the only thing that works for me is:

```
document.addEventListener()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That error means that your variable `button1` is null. Are you 100% certain there is an element in your HTML with the id of `mybutton1`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" means that `button1` is a null. You haven't get the specific thing, button. You've made mistake in the code

`var button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton1");`

Try to correct this code and you'll get the correct response. Or you may show the html of the page to found the issue?